# How to Hide Navigation Bar Title in ScrollView in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, navigationbar

In Swift, this would be the code

```
navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true
```

however, this does not work in SwiftUI

I currently have a scroll view within a navigation view, and then I placed the navigation bar title here.

How do I hide the `NavigationBarTitle` as it scrolls down deep enough?

Comment: Take a look at this accepted answer, hope this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61324597/hide-navigation-bar-on-swipe-of-a-list-in-swiftui?noredirect=1&lq=1